# javascript object variable is not changing

Tags: javascript

i want the regis.checksum convert to 1 so that if block does not run the next time. i am also new to stackoverflow. Thanks in advance for the help`

```
var regis = {
        checksum : 0,
        username : false,
        first_name : false,
        password : false,
        password_check : false
    }

if( $("#id_username").val().trim() == ""){
    if(regis['checksum']==0){
        alert(regis.checksum)
        $("#id_username").focus(function(){
            $("#error_username").text("Your email id will be created with this name");
            regis['checksum'] = 1
        })
    }else{
        $("#id_username").on('input', function() {
            alert("Change to " + this.value);
        });
    }
}`
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: @Yogesh the regis.checksum is only changing the value in local scope, however i want it to change the global regis.checksum

Comment: is your `regis` object declared outside document ready?

Comment: no its declared inside $(function(){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function(){
  var regis = {
            checksum : 0,
            username : false,
            first_name : false,
            password : false,
            password_check : false
        };


  function validate(value){
      if(!value){
        $("#error_username").text("Username field cannot be left empty");
      } else if(value.indexOf(" ") > -1){
        $("#error_username").text("Username field cannot have spaces");
      } else {
        $("#error_username").text("");
      }
  }

  $("#id_username").focus(function(){
   if(regis.checksum === 0){
     console.log(regis.checksum)
     $("#error_username").text("Your email id will be created with this name");
     regis.checksum = 1
   } else {
     validate($("#id_username").val());
   }
  });


  $("#id_username").on('input', function() {
    if(regis.checksum === 1){
      validate($("#id_username").val());
    }
  });
})()
```

http://jsbin.com/paridad/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: the function seems to go in a loop

Comment: @gauravsamant: what is the usecase... ?

Comment: I want to create a registration form. the concept is if the user focus 1st time into username it will display the string "it will be your email username" else it will display if the field is empty or irregular

Comment: @gauravsamant: i have updated the code.. you can checkit out at http://jsbin.com/paridad/edit?html,js,console,output